# [rospack] Error: stack/package roscpp not found

Tags: roscpp, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro.

While creating a package in one of my directories, i wrote the following line of code to the terminal (because i was facing the problem mentioned in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11639/how-to-update-ros_package_path/)):

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/<PATH TO THE DIRECTORY I WAS MAKING THE PACKAGE IN>
```

After adding this line, i'm facing this error:

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package roscpp not found
```

whenever i type the following code:

```
rospack find roscpp
```

Although the package `roscpp` is still present at this path: `/opt/ros/hydro/share$`

What is causing this issue?
How do i solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214617/%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-roscpp-not-found/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What is causing this issue?

With:

> ```
> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/<PATH TO THE DIRECTORY I WAS MAKING THE PACKAGE IN>
> ```

you are *overwriting* the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable, so that it *only* points to `~/<PATH TO THE DIRECTORY I WAS MAKING THE PACKAGE IN>`. The default paths needed for ROS to function are now gone, hence the error message you received.

If you really must change/update `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` manually, be sure to only *add* to it. Something like:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/path/to/dir/i/was/making/pkg/in:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

This inserts the new path *and* copies in the old entries.

> How do i solve it?

Depending on how you setup your system, simply opening a new terminal could restore the old `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` values. Alternatively, `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` should also set the variable to its default value.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1